# Using forEach method to target each button independently and display it's corresponding "share-container"

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach

I got this code to work but it I got a bug. It is opening and closing all 12 elements collectively (".share-btn-container").
Trying to get it to target only the button clicked, and it's corresponding share-btn-container.
I suspect it has something to do with the "let sharePanelOpen = true".

```
//HTML 
//12 of those divs, all sharing the "share-btns" class and "share-btn-container" class.

<button id ="share-song1" class ="share-btns"><span class ="fa">&#xf1e0</span></button> 
            <div id ="share-container1" class ="share-btn-container">
            <a href="#" id="facebookshare1" class ="facebook-btn"><i class ="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="whatsappshare1" class ="whatsapp-btn"><i class ="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="twittershare1"  class ="twitter-btn"><i class ="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#" id="linkedinshare1" class ="linkedin-btn"><i class ="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
         </div>

//Javascript

let sharePanelOpen = false;

const shareButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.share-btns');
const shareContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.share-btn-container');

function openSharePanel () {
    shareContainers.forEach((container) => {
      console.log(container);
      sharePanelOpen = true;
      container.classList.add('share-btn-container-active');          
    })
      shareButtons.forEach((button) => {
        button.classList.add('share-btns-active');
    })
}

function closeSharePanel () {
    shareContainers.forEach((container) => {
      sharePanelOpen = false;
      container.classList.remove('share-btn-container-active');          
    })
      shareButtons.forEach((button) => {
        button.classList.remove('share-btns-active');
    })
}

shareButtons.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => { 
      togglesharePanel();    
   })
})

function togglesharePanel() {sharePanelOpen ? closeSharePanel() : openSharePanel();}

//CSS

.share-btn-container {
    display: none;
}

.share-btn-container-active {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 78px;
    left: 66px;
    background: rgb(30,10,40);
    border:  1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
    border-radius: 6%;
    width: 14.2rem;
    height: 7rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 4;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use `sharePanelOpen` just pass reference of sharedContainer of corresponding button using it's index when you register click event for each button. Then in `togglesharePanel()` function just use toggle method of classList to add / remove 'share-btn-container-active' class

for example

```
const shareButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.share-btns');
const shareContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.share-btn-container');


shareButtons.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => { 
      togglesharePanel(shareContainers[i]);    
   })
})

function togglesharePanel(shareContainersRef) {
  shareContainersRef.classList.toggle('share-btn-container-active')
}
```

Comment: Yea! That was works a charm. Thank you!
Now I'm trying to get it to target the buttons too and apply the active class to
the right button.

Comment: I copied your template and added the ('share-btns-active') class to the forEach.
Now it works just like how I wanted.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
const shareButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.share-btns');
const shareContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.share-btn-container');

shareButtons.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => { 
      togglesharePanel(shareContainers[i]);
      toggleshareBtns(shareButtons[i])    
   })
})

function togglesharePanel(shareContainersRef) {
  shareContainersRef.classList.toggle('share-btn-container-active')
  console.log(shareContainersRef);
}

function toggleshareBtns(buttonref) {
  buttonref.classList.toggle('share-btns-active')
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).